# Incorrect UISwitch appearance in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, uiswitch

I created a sectioned `UITableView` and added a custom cell that includes a `UISwitch`. All this is done using the storyboard. However, when running the App (Simulator/device), the `UISwitch` does not look as expected (c.f. attached screenshot). 
Any ideas on why this happened are highly appreciated (XCode 4.5.2, iOS 6.0.1). Note: creating a new UIStoryboard does not solve the problem.

[image: UISwitch in custom UITableView]
[image: UISwitch settings]

Comment: "UISwitch looks weird" - complain to Apple's designers if you don't like it ;)

Comment: Are you trying to customize the look of that switch?

Comment: @H2CO3 If you would like to suggest an improvement to the title of my question: feel free to edit it.

Comment: @AceLegend no, I just added a regular switch

Comment: @tilo, !!! Yikes! That is bad. I have no idea why that would happen. Could you show us the settings you picked on the IB. Thanks!

Comment: @AceLegend added another screenshot (note that these should be the standard settings)

Comment: I've had weird issues with customizing UITableViewCell in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method. Try placing your UISwitch on the cell inside the tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath delegate method, and see if anything changes.

Comment: @diatrevolo unfortunately, the result is the same. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Probably you placed it under the cell. Have you tried to delete it and add again?

Comment: @Flink I checked this when adding the switch programmatically as the accessoryView of the cell

Comment: @tilo Can we see this code?

Comment: Sure: `UISwitch *switch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]; cell.accessoryView = switch;`

Comment: +1 because I like pictures.

Comment: Is this simple to reproduce in a new project? If I try and look at this, will I get the same by just adding a switch as an accessory view to a table cell? Because I've done exactly that before on other projects and its been fine, though this does look like a possible Autolayout issue.

Comment: @jrturton Unfortunately, you won't get the same result in a new project. Any advice on how to solve this without starting off with a new project?

Comment: I can't solve it until I've reproduced it!

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you instead add the switch as a subview, rather than setting the view directly? (i.e:
`UISwitch *s = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame/*Frame of accessoryView*/]; [cell.accessoryView addSubview:s];`)

Comment: @PLPiper Adding the switch as a subview to the accessoryView, it is not visible at all. Adding it as a subview to the contentView, it has the same incorrect appearance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got the answer to my question: I created a category on `UIImageView` that sets custom layer properties (e.g. `shadowRadius`). Setting a breakpoint on the corresponding `UIImageView` method, it revealed that the `UISwitch` called it.

I did not get to this point earlier, as I only had a single `UIImageView` before (and this one was supposed to have custom properties). Thanks for all your comments!